# Execvp not executing args

Tags: c, execvp

I can't get execvp to execute the args, this code only works if I set the number of args to 0.  I've been trying to change lines here and there for 2 hours and checking other similar questions but nothing is working, maybe someone got an idea?

```
void executeProgram()
{
    char *argv[20];
    printf("Please enter command or program name:");
    char *commande;
    scanf("%s", commande);
    argv[0] = malloc(100);
    argv[0] = commande;
    int nbArgZ = -1;
    while(nbArgZ < 0){
            printf("Please enter number of arguments:");
            scanf("%d", &nbArgZ);
    }
    int x;
    int y =1;
    for(x = 1; x < nbArgZ+1; x++){
            char *tempo;
            argv[x] = malloc(100);
            printf("Argument %d : ", x);
            scanf("%s", tempo);
            argv[x] = tempo;
            y++;
    }
    argv[y] = NULL;
    int pid = fork();
    if ( pid == 0 ) {
            execvp(argv[0], argv);
    }
    wait(2);
    printf( "End of execution\n");
}
```

Comment: `char *commande;` is an uninitialized pointer. You can't use it in the `scanf` until you allocate some memory for it.

Comment: but commande is the only one working, it's the other argv[] that doesn't seem to work

Comment: the obvious question is - did you use your debugger to look at argv and make sure it has what you expect to be in it

Comment: Using uninitialized pointer is *Undefined Behavior*. Anything can happen, including program seeming to work right. Debugging further is basically pointless, until you fix UB.

Comment: it should be, i'm passing it the same way i'm doing with commande, otherwise how would I pass the values?

Comment: what `wait(2)` does ?

Comment: Another thing, always check return value of *scanf* family of functions. If there is parse error (or some other error), then the variables in parameters will be unset, and your program will do funny things, and debugging is kind of pointless. For learning/experimental/quick&dirty code, you can just exit the program on parse error, for real programs you'd have to do something more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code

```
   argv[0] = malloc(100);
    argv[0] = commande;
```

should set off alarm bells immediately. You assign something toe argv[0], then in the next line set it to something else. That cannot be correct

you need

```
char commande[100]; // we will assume 100 is enough
scanf("%s", commande);
argv[0] = strdup(commande); // strdup maybe not needed, buts lets be safe
```

and the same change inside your arg loop

Comment: I'll try your code, but commande is the only one working actually, try my code with arguments set to 0, it's when I try to add arguments that it doesn't work

Comment: my last line points out that you need the same fix in that loop too. Basically after your first scanf everything else is moot. You are in UB land, you cannot reason about UB,

Comment: Yeah it works, I corrected both commande and the loop, but it's wierd that it was working for commande but not the args ... !

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I thought it could be array assignation problem, but since commande was working I thought it had to be something else

Answer (score 2):

You have *multiple* problems. Here are a couple of them:

```
argv[x] = malloc(100);
...
argv[x] = tempo;
```

First you make `argv[x]` point to some memory you allocate, then you make `argv[x]` point to where `tempo` is pointing, making you lose the original memory.

And about `tempo`:

```
char *tempo;
...
scanf("%s", tempo);
```

You have an uninitialized pointer. Where it is pointing is *indeterminate* and will seem almost random. Dereferencing this pointer, which happens when you call `scanf`, leads to *undefined behavior*.

Both of these issue can be solved by passing `argv[x]` directly to your `scanf` call:

```
scanf("%99s", argv[x]);  // No more than 99 characters (excluding terminator)
```

---

And you have the very same problem not once, but *twice*.